# .SH/.COMMAND Bash File Mac OSX Not working

Tags: macos, bash, sh

I keep getting this error for my script below when I try to run it

The file “test.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges.

Tried changing the read only to read/write. Didn't work

```
for domain in $(pwgen -1A0B 6 10000); do echo -ne "$domain.com "; if [ -z "$(whois    $domain.com | grep -o 'No match for')" ]; then echo -ne "Not "; fi; echo "Available for register"; done >> domains.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to give execute permission as well to execute it.

```
chmod u+x file
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, I'm still a little confused. Step by step do I just have to add that into the beginning of the script?